# Time limit exceeded - Fibonacci

Tags: c, linked-list, fibonacci

There are 'n' fibonacci numbers in a list where 'n' is provided by user. After reading, modify the numbers by taking mod with 10 (for ex. If I read 2 then it should be modified to 2%10 i.e. 2 and If it's 13 then it should be 13%10 i.e. 3).Then, remove every odd-positioned number(1, 3, 5...positioned items) from that list until you are left with just one item.

I've solved the problem. But, the issue is that I'm getting TLE error. I've tried shortening the code but still can get it under a second.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int fib(int n)
{
    if(n == 0 || n == 1)
    {
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        return(fib(n-1)+fib(n-2));
    }
}

int main()
{
    int ip, d, i=0, j, n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &ip);
        if(ip == 1)
        {
            printf("0\n");
        }
        else if(ip == 2)
        {
            printf("1\n");
        }
        else if(ip == 4)
        {
            printf("2\n");
        }
        else
        {
            while(1)
            {
                d = pow(2, i++);
                if(d >= ip)
                {
                    d = pow(2, i-2);
                    break;
                }
            }
            printf("%d", fib(d-1)%10);
        }
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The example below the main text does not seem to be correct. 11 is not a fibonacci number.

Comment: TLE means your program takes too long to run. Perhaps if you remembered the last two numbers you calculated you could calculate the next one without starting from the beginning.

Comment: @g_bor sorry, it should be 13 and 21 respectively.

Comment: Also note, that the number that remains is only depenedent on the length, not on any of the values. Can you guess the index of the number that you will have to output?

Comment: @g_bor It'll vary according to different inputs. Now, If I input no. test cases as 1 and then input 23, then 23 fibonacci numbers are entered into the list. Then I delete (1st, 3rd, 5th...) every odd node. Now, I've got a new list. From this, I must repeat the process until a single node is left. This way, I get 0 as the last remaining node.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Actually, for each test case, for eg. there are 2 test cases, and I enter input length of fibonacci sequence as 9 for 1st, it prints 3. After that, I should enter input for 2nd case, let's say that the input is 4 this time, then it prints 2. There can be many test cases, and, for each case I have to fill the list, then modify, print and again repeat the process by emptying the list.

Comment: 1. You don't need to actually remove nodes or even traverse all of them - only act as if you had (calculate the node you need and traverse to it once) ... 2. You don't use the modulus value until the end - only compute it then; there's no point in doing work that just gets discarded  3. This can be done with a single loop.

Comment: @technosaurus The input depends on user. Like if I enter 4 then, list will have 0 1 1 2, followed by, 1 2, and 2. But, for a much larger value, how can I just skip it? I'll only know which node is left at last once I've deleted the remaining ones. It would've worked if the fibonacci numbers to be added to the list were fixed. Like, if 4 was the only input, then I know 2 is going to be the output. But, for 12, it'll be 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89, followed by 1 2 5 3 4 9 then 2 3 9 and at last 3 is left.

Comment: So, to clarify my first point, in case of 1 23 input, it can still be easily found out from having a look at only 23, and the way you remove the items.

Comment: Also, independently from that, you can also find out a value at index n:
1. first, note that you can do all the calculation using only the mod 10 remainders all the time,
2. then notice that this becomes a recursively define series, where the actual value is dependent only the previous two values, and is defined on the [0-9] finite alphabet
3. there are only 100 disjoint following character pairs in that, so the series is of the form:
4. an ititial segment of maximally 100 elements, and then becomes periodic with a maximal period of 100.

Comment: @KuljeetK there's a pattern - you just aren't seeing it.  Try doing it with a numbered sequence instead of Fibonacci and printing out the results without doing any modulo, then it should be more apparent.   You are determining how many nodes to traverse to get to the one that would have been left if you did it the slow, obvious way - even if you can't figure out the math for this, it should be obvious that you don't need to do the modulus value until the end ON 1 NODE not all the ones that are discarded  (for this - real programs may need that modified data)

Comment: @technosaurus I think I get it now. So, if I my input was 9. If I just, shortlist using 9 itself, I get 8. And then pass this 8 in fib function which will give me 13 as output which can be modified to 3.

Comment: Now you're on the right track.

Comment: For extra credit show how the calculated position relates to the most significant bit of the user's node count input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimization comes usually comes in steps.

You start off with the obvious solution.

```
iterate_fibs_mod10; remove_odds(n);
```

Then you realize that you really only need the expensive modulus once for one element.

```
nth_fib(remove_odds(n))%10;
```

Then you realize you don't need to remove the nodes if you can deterministically find which one would have remained.

```
nth_fib(as_if_remove_odds(n))%10;
```

Then you figure out that the element corresponds to a mathematical function.

```
nth_fib((int)log2(n))%10;
```

Then you realize that this corresponds to the most significant bit in binary representation.

```
nth_fib(msb_only(n))%10; //compiler builtins exist for most significant bit
```

Then you notice that since you are only doing the last digit, the sequence must repeat within 100 iterations (it happens to be 60), so you can do a lookup table.

```
unsigned char fib_1s[60] = {...};
fib_1s[msb_only(n)%60];
```